# Spring: ModelAttribute doesn't get called

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-annotations, modelattribute

I have a controller used to display a list of project, but I cannot find why a @ModelAttribute method doesn't get called.

This is my controller:

```
@Controller(value = "projectListController")
@RequestMapping(value = "VIEW")
public class ProjectListController {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("projectService")
private ProjectService projectService;

@RenderMapping
public String showProjects() {

    return "projectList";
}

@ModelAttribute("projectListCount")
public Long getProjectListCount() {

    return projectService.getProjectListCount();
}

@ModelAttribute("projectFilter")
public ProjectFilter getProjectFilter(
        @RequestParam(value = "cur", required = false) String curString,
        @RequestParam(value = "delta", required = false) String deltaString,
        @RequestParam(value = "orderByCol", required = false) String orderByCol,
        @RequestParam(value = "orderByType", required = false) String orderByType) {

    return new ProjectFilter(curString, deltaString, orderByCol, orderByType);
}

@ModelAttribute("projectList")
public List<TPrProgetti> getProjectList(
        @ModelAttribute("projectFilter") ProjectFilter projectFilter) {

    return projectService.getProgettiList(projectFilter.getCur(), projectFilter.getDelta(),
            projectFilter.getOrderByCol(), projectFilter.isAsc());
}
}
```

The order in which the method are invokated is this:

1. Model projectListCount
2. Model projectList
3. Render projectList

I don't understand why the Model projectFilter doesn't get called, being used as a parameter in the render method.
What I see is that Spring prefer to call the constructor of ProjectFilter and setting its fields through setters. How this mapping is done is another matter...

## EDIT

Just to complete and answer to the comment, this project is a portlet deployed in Liferay and it uses using Spring.

The jsp was like this:

```
<liferay-ui:search-container emptyResultsMessage="No project found"
    orderByCol="${projectFilter.orderByCol}" orderByType="${projectFilter.orderByType}"
    delta="${projectFilter.delta}">
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results total="${progettiCount}"
        results="${projectList}">
    </liferay-ui:search-container-results>

    <liferay-ui:search-container-row
        className="it.eng.liferay.portlet.domain.TPrProgetti" keyProperty="id" modelVar="project">
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Codice" property="codProg"  orderable="<%= true %>" orderableProperty="codProg"/>
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Descrizione"  property="descrizione" orderable="<%= true %>" orderableProperty="descrizione"/>
        </liferay-ui:search-container-row>
    <liferay-ui:search-iterator />
</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

Comment: can you post your form please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used one ModelAttribute method that contains every ModelAttribute like this:

```
@ModelAttribute
public void populateModel(Model model,
        @RequestParam(value = "cur", required = false) String curString,
        @RequestParam(value = "delta", required = false) String deltaString,
        @RequestParam(value = "orderByCol", required = false) String orderByCol,
        @RequestParam(value = "orderByType", required = false) String orderByType) {

    model.addAttribute("progettiCount", projectService.getProgettiCount());
    model.addAttribute("projectFilter", projectFilter);
    model.addAttribute("projectList", projectService.getProgettiList(projectFilter.getCur(), projectFilter.getDelta(),
                    projectFilter.getOrderByCol(), projectFilter.isAsc()));
}
```

I don't like it very much, but it works.

I tried also using the latest version of Spring that is 4.0.5, but the problem didn't change.

Comment: Do you already have a modelattribute projectFilter in your form?